# How can one find this limit

Tags: real-analysis

How can one find this limit without L hospital?

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (1+\tan x)^{2/x}$$

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this is correct, but:

- Since $\tan x \sim \sin x $ when $x \to 0$, and $\sin x \sim x$ when $x \to 0$, then
- the limit can be calculated as:

$$L = \lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)^{2/x} = \left(\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{1/x}\right)^2 = e^2$$

Cheers!

Comment: Yes your answer is correct! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Using the Taylor series the result is pretty simple:
$$(1+\tan x)^{2/x}=\exp\left(\frac 2 x \log(1+\tan x)\right)\sim_0\exp\left(\frac 2 x\log(1+x)\right)\sim_0 e^2$$