# How can I find this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How can I find this integral? please help

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{e^{-\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}\ dx.$$

Comment: Dear mohd, as you've been [told](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/638451/89121) already, this community has a consensus that simply asking questions without ever including your attempts to solve them and/or understanding of the underlying concepts is undesirable. Please consider participating in this site in a more constructive manner in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Set  $\displaystyle\sqrt x=u\implies \frac{dx}{2\sqrt x}=du$

When $x=0,u=0$ and for $x=1,u=\sqrt1=1$

$$I=2\int_0^1e^{-u}du=2\cdot\frac{e^{-u}}{-1}\large|_0^1$$

Comment: @Downvoter, would you mind pinpointing the mistake?

Comment: I wan't the one, but since everything seems in order with the answer, may I venture a guess that it's the manner in which you've supplied and instant-answer to this question (considering OP's record) that's at the root of it?

Comment: Please: the function is not continuous at zero

Comment: @mohd, http://goo.gl/VyffU8

Comment: @mohd, Observe that the function is not defined in real, for $x<0$.